# datatable rows getting hidden on changing sorting order in angular

Tags: angular, datatable, angular-datatables

my data table loads first but when i click on column to change sort order, entire table becomes empty in angular project

user.comp.html

```
<tbody>
   <tr *ngFor="let user of userData" id="{{ user.description }}">
<td class="col-xs-2 smallcol">{{ user.userId }}</td> 
<td class="ellipses col-xs-8">{{ user.description }}</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

user.comp.ts

```
ngonInit(): void{
this.client Service.getUserList().subscribe({

next: userData => {

this.userData = userData;

}

});
```

user.serv.ts

```
getUserList():Observable<IUser[]>
return this.http.post<Iuser[]>(restAPIUrl.getUserList,httpOptions);
```

Answer (score 0):

To use sorting,pagination etc features of DataTable in Angular, you need to use the dtOptions properly. Adding example below :

```
dtOptions: any = {};
ngOnInit(){
  this.dtOptions = {
  pagingType: 'full_numbers',
  pageLength: 5,
  lengthMenu : [5, 10, 25],
  processing: true
  };
}
```